# Using SetCurrentDir and WinExec32AndWait within TParallel.For skips some iterations

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a problem with number of iterations in Tparallel.for.
i have 100 folder and in each folder exist a file to be run (run.bat).
After run the out.txt file is created in folder.when i use Tparalle.for with 100 iterations, i recieve randomly 90 to 98 out.txt  while it be 100.
my code is as below  (Delphi XE7):

```
TParallel.For(1, 100, procedure(i: integer)
    begin
      SetCurrentDir(path + '\test\' + IntToStr(i));
      WinExec32AndWait(PChar('run.bat'), 0);
    end);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what's the problem? What are you expecting and what's the real outcome? Might also like to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 3):

The process working directory is a single value for the process. You are expecting each task to have their own private copy but that is simply not how the working directory operates. In more technical terms there is a data race on the shared process wide working directory. Because of this race when the child processes are created they inherit the working directory of the parent but because of the race some children are inheriting the working directory intended for different children. This is one of the classic mistakes made with parallel programming.

Deal with this by avoiding use of the parent process working directory. Do not modify it at all. Instead pass the working directory to each child process as you create them. This can be done quite simply using `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx`. Your `WinExec32AndWait` function may need to be modified to accept a working directory argument.

This solves the problem by ensuring that you create a separate copy of the working directory for each distinct child process.

Comment: WinExec32AndWait function is as below:

Comment: function WinExec32AndWait(const Cmd: string; const CmdShow: Integer): Cardinal;
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  Result := Cardinal($FFFFFFFF);
  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);

Comment: StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;//STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW//NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := CmdShow;

Comment: if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(Cmd), nil, nil, false,HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS,
    nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then

  begin
    WaitForInputIdle(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    if WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
    begin
      if not GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, Result) then
        Result := Cardinal($FFFFFFFF);
    end;

Comment: CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
  end;
end;

Comment: I'm actually not terribly interested in writing your program for you. What I've attempted to do here is explain **why** your code fails and **what** you should do to fix it. I'm here to help people learn. If you want to learn, great. If you don't want to learn, and just want somebody to feed you code, I am the wrong person for you.

Comment: @AMIR if you have additional informations for your question then you should edit the question. Do not flood us with code in comments - noone is going to puzzle that comment parts together

Comment: Finally i solved my problem. For determining  current directory, i used   CreateProcess  instead setcurrentdir.  CreateProcess  function used in WinExec32AndWait.                                                                CreateProcess(nil, PChar(Cmd), nil, nil, false,HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, Currentdir, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo)

Comment: Which is exactly what I said

Answer (score 0):

setcurrentdir is off course not multithread! what if 2 thread at the same time set the current dir to xxx  ? :)

do instead

```
Tparallel.for(1,100.procedure(i:integer)
begin
  winexec32andwait(pchar(path+'\test\'+inttostr(i) + '\run.bat'),0);
end);
```

Comment: Probably need to set the working directory in the child process too

Comment: if  use  winexec32andwait  without setcurrentdir , run.bat file  would not be run.

Comment: @AMIR SetCurrentDir sets the **global** current dir for the current process. After that you start the process with the batch. You forget about multithreading aspect. task1 set current dir, task2 set current dir, task1 starts the batch (oops, on wrong current dir) - that is your problem

Comment: @AMIR I added a '\' before 'run.bat'. See above. Please try again. Assuming you have '<yourpath>\test\1\run.bat', etc.